# Java NIO UDP Multicast - dropped packets

Tags: java, udp, nio, multicast

We have a logging system that uses UDP multicast to send log events. The event rate is around 10,000 events/sec and the average event size is around 2Kb.

The NIO version of the application loses a minor percentage of events (~2000 events in about 12M) during every test. Does anyone have any insights in this regard ?

Sample Code:
Without NIO:

```
    byte[] buf = new byte[65535];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

    try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            socket.receive(packet);

            final byte[] tmpBuffer = new byte[packet.getLength()];
            System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), 0, tmpBuffer, 0,
                    tmpBuffer.length);

            insertToNonBlockingQueue(tmpBuffer, packet.getSocketAddress());
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Encountered exception in Acceptor", t);
    } finally {
        Util.closeQuietly(socket);
    }
```

With NIO:

```
    ByteBuffer inBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(65535);
    try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            SocketAddress addr = channel.receive(inBuffer);

            inBuffer.flip();

            final byte[] tmpBuffer = new byte[inBuffer.limit()];
            inBuffer.get(tmpBuffer);

            inBuffer.clear();

            insertToNonBlockingQueue(tmpBuffer, addr);
        }
    } catch (ClosedByInterruptException ex) {
        log.info("Channel closed by interrupt"); // normal shutdown
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Encountered exception in Acceptor", t);
    } finally {
        Util.closeQuietly(channel);
    }
```

Both the listeners are run at the same time and every time the non NIO version captures all the log events while the NIO version misses a few. It is not a network issues because, it is the same behaviour even when we switch the code to the other version on a machine.

Comment: sorry, i missed to include the clear when I copy pasted the code, i had the buffer.clear() in the code and I have edited the posting to reflect it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `compact()` or `clear()` the buffer after the `get()`. This code will start dropping packets as soon as the buffer fills.

The `DatagramPacket` case should reset the packet length before every receive.

It would be simpler to insert the actual `DatagramPacket` into the queue and use a new one per receive, or synthesise a new one in the NIO case. That way you don't need a new data structure.

Comment: I did not use a new DatagramPacket everytime in Non NIO case because there the event sizes range from 200bytes to 64K (max) and the average is < 2K, i did not want to insert a packet with 64K data in the queue for each event. However since the queue size rarely goes beyond a few thousands (unless there are bigger issues), i think your suggesstion to use a new DatagramPacket everytime will perform better (support even higher event rates).

Comment: For the NIO case, i had the clear(), copy paste fail on my part when i posted the question, i will test with the DirectByteBuffer. (I took that your last sentence refers to the Non-NIO case instead of NIO)

Comment: It refers to both cases.

Comment: In what universe is this the accepted answer? How could `It refers to both cases.` apply to both cases? There is no get in the non-NIO case, so that makes zero sense. Also, it makes no sense because the OP even said that they just forgot to put the `clear` in the code snippet, but it was in fact there in the real code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what EJP said, you should use a direct byte buffer as read buffer, otherwise the socket will internally allocate a DBB, then copy from that into your BB and then you'll copy from that into the array. I.e. there's a superfluous copy operation.

Additionally you may want to configure the socket's receive buffer to a size that can hold multiple packets.